# Where to find proper maven-project version?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin

While debugging a plugin I'm writing, I came across a problem with maven-project dependency resolution.

My project has dependency to version 2.0.8, maven-dependency-plugin:2.8 points to same version, but in Eclipse random lines are highlighted in sources for MavenProject class.

I've tried finding a proper version, and have a feeling that one of 3.0-alphas is being used

Is it possible that Maven provides even later version of maven-project is used by maven itself (for instance 3.0-alpha-2), but Eclipse fails to resolve this?

BTW: I've tried finding a repo with maven-project and failed to do so. Where is it maintained.

UPDATE:
My dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
        <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-exec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
        <artifactId>plexus-archiver</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twdata.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>mojo-executor</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In my PrepareDependenciesMojo, I run mojo-executor like this:

```
@Mojo( name = "prepare-dependencies", requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.COMPILE )
public class PrepareDependenciesMojo
extends AbstractMojo
{

@Parameter( defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true, required = true )
private MavenProject project;

@Parameter( defaultValue = "${session}", readonly = true, required = true )
private MavenSession session;

@Component( role = BuildPluginManager.class )
private BuildPluginManager pluginManager;

/**
 * Based on dependencies entered, selects what to copy and what to copy and unpack.
 * 
 * @throws MojoExecutionException .
 * @throws MojoFailureException when plugin execution result was other than expected
 * @see org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo#execute()
 */
public void execute()
    throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException
{
    executeMojoWithLogs( "org.apache.maven.plugins", "maven-dependency-plugin", "2.8", "copy-dependencies",
                         configuration() );
    executeMojoWithLogs( "org.apache.maven.plugins", "maven-dependency-plugin", "2.8", "unpack-dependencies",
                         configuration() );
}

private void executeMojoWithLogs( String groupId, String artifactId, String version, String goal,
                                  Xpp3Dom configuration )
    throws MojoExecutionException
{
    getLog().info( String.format( "--- %s:%s:%s (call within prepare-dependencies) @ empty-project ---",
                                  artifactId, version, goal ) );
    getLog().debug( configuration.toString() );
    executeMojo(
                 plugin(
                         groupId( groupId ),
                         artifactId( artifactId ),
                         version( version )
                 ),
                 goal( goal ),
                 configuration,
                 executionEnvironment( project, session, pluginManager ) );

    getLog().info( String.format( "--- %s:%s:%s ended ---",
                                  artifactId, version, goal ) );

}

}
```

I entered doExecute within copy-dependencies, but in it, first method retrieves artifacts from MavenProject - there I was getting inproper source code for the dependency.

Comment: Currently Maven has the up-to-date version 3.1.1 which means you can use maven-project in version 3.1.1. But the question is to which Maven version would you like to be compatible with your plugin? Apart from the maven-project has not really changed between 2.2.1 and 3.0.X and 3.1.1. Furthermore it would be helpfull if you can post the current pom file you have.

Comment: Clearly, I am missing something. I went to http://search.maven.org/ and entered maven-project - there is no such version: 3.1.1

As for my pom: I updated my question.

Comment: Sorry my fault. Use maven-project 2.2.1. Can you explain what you like to achieve with the calls to maven-dependency-plugin ?

Comment: I want to copy dependencies to target's subfolder. In my project type, the project file relies on dependencies and I want them to be relative to root of project, as the tool I'm trying to handle is not maven-aware and may use absolute paths, causing problems for the whole build on a different machine :)

I found the root cause of my issue through RTFM philosophy, but still haven't managed to get the right sources.

Now some of the dependencies need to be unpacked and I have another issue which seems to be an unpack-dependencies goal bug, but still cannot easily debug it.